# Laravel attach arrays of data to pivot

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to attach arrays of data. I have collection of products and try to get individual items, and insert into pivot table. I don't want to put attach in loop because I want one db call

```
if($cart->packages)
    {
        foreach( $cart->packages as $k => $v)
        {
            $collection = Collection::find($k)->products;
            // dd($collection);
            $records_array[] = $k;
            $name[]['name'] = $v['name'];
            $quantity[]['quantity'] = $v['quantity'];
        }
        // dd($records_array);
        $order->collections()->attach($records_array,  $name, $quantity);
    }
```

Comment: Sø you want to insert multiple data at once with out for loop

Comment: check my answer, btw little note, since I do not have all your development code so I did it from the knowledge I have gathered from your question. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to import `DB` facade some where after namespace and before class name:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

The in your controller added following for testing:

```
$cart = array(
    array('name' => 'some product 1', 'quantity' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'some product 2', 'quantity' => '2'),
    array('name' => 'some product 3', 'quantity' => '1'),
);

if ($cart)
{
    DB::table('order')->insert($cart);
}
```

I have tested on my local environment and it works.

You can take look at **[Running An Insert Statement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database)**

Comment: put is there oprion to use attach?

Comment: Can you Send me your table and some data sample Find My email in My profile i will give it a look

Comment: i am trying to group data by months and sum price    $order = Order::select(DB::raw('sum(price) as views'))->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m');

})->get();